# Как сделать выборку объектов со значениям параметра либо равным переменной, либо пустым?

Tags: python, django

Есть модель с атрибутом типа DecimalField, в который может быть записано пустое значение:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model)
    width = models.DecimalField(
      max_digits=5, 
      decimal_places=2, 
      blank=True, 
      null=True)
```

Теперь я хочу выбрать экземпляры этой модели со значением width либо пустым, либо равным определенному значению:

```py
some_value = 10
qs = MyModel.objects.all.filter(width__in=[some_value, None])
```

В таком виде это не матчится с пустыми значениями, видимо потому что пустое значение и None это все-таки не одно и то же. Но если сделать, например, вот так:

```py
some_value = 10
qs = MyModel.objects.all.filter(width__in=[some_value, '', None])
```

то это дает ошибку, т.к. значение width не может быть равно строке.

Как правильно решить мою задачу?

Comment: decimal не может иметь пустое значение (если не считать нуль): он или NULL (значения вообще нет), или не NULL

Comment: В силу особенностей SQL проверка на NULL должна делаться отдельно от всех остальных проверок, что-то вроде `WHERE width IS NOT NULL OR width = some_value` (как это записать в Django, я к сожалению не помню)

Comment: `.filter(width_isnull=True)`

Comment: @Jazzis а что насчёт some_value?

Comment: @andreymal идею я конечно понял, но пока не представляю как сделать то, что я хочу) Мне в конечном итоге нужно посчитать количество записей у которых либо null либо мое значение.

Comment: @andreymal или хотя бы проверить что такие записи вообще существуют. Только атрибут не один, а сразу много.

Comment: Можно попробовать через `Q` составить запрос: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects.

Comment: Например, `Q(width_isnull=True) | Q(width=some_value)`

Comment: @Jazzis я как раз в эту сторону пошел, но Q ругается на использование isnull: Cannot resolve keyword 'isnull' into field.

Comment: @Jazzis, а нужно же width_isnull, я затупил че-то. Сейчас попробую

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров я чуток ошибся: `width__isnull` с двумя `__` должен быть

Comment: @Jazzis почему-то не матчится, хотя это довольно странно. Должно ведь)

Comment: @andreymal  а когда в админке сохраняешь поле decimal field, при этом точно в базу null пишется? Использую postgresql. Вариант с Q должен работать, везде про него пишут( Но именно `width__isnull=True` он не матчит почему-то.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Только что проверил ваш код. `Q` должен работать. Например, `MyModel.objects.filter(Q(width__isnull=True) | Q(width=123))` корректно выводит `<QuerySet [<MyModel: None>, <MyModel: 123.00>]>`.

Comment: @Jazzis да, это я как обычно не тот параметр удалил, который проверял) Большое спасибо! Оформите как ответ, отмечу как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать через [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) сделать:

```python
from django.db.models import Q

MyModel.objects.filter(Q(width__isnull=True) | Q(width=123))

# <QuerySet [<MyModel: None>, <MyModel: 123.00>]>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
some_value = 10
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(width__isnull=True) | MyModel.objects.filter(width = some_value)
```

Comment: Вы сами-то пробовали запускать этот код?

Comment: Прошу прощения, до этого полнейшую глупость написал, поправил код

Comment: Вопрос от этого не изменился.

Comment: @Jazzis да, пробовал, капсуляция через Q, которую вы предлагаете выше, подходит для единичных объектов, у меня решение для фильтрации нескольких объектов

Comment: а если так надо проверить 10 атрибутов в рамках одной выборки?))

Comment: @Константин Комиссаров перечисляйте все условия через дизъюнкцию

Comment: @super16 а что значит "подходит для единичных объектов"?

Comment: @Константин Комиссаров если нужно найти объект из выборки через `get` или `exclude`

Comment: @super16 под вопросом в комментах провели эксперимент и вроде как через Q нормально делается выборка из нескольких объектов. Гляньте.